# How to use cookies in Azure function HttpTriggers (Node)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I see that there is a 'cookie' key inside the `headers` property of the request object but nothing else.

I cant find anything related to cookies in the documentation either.

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {

  context.res = {
    body: "Something"
  };

  // how do I send cookies ??

  context.done();
}
```

Comment: Just for plain curiosity...why do you want to use a cookie inside an Azure Function?...maybe if you are able to capture the http context inside the function, you can have access to any cookie or header set on the petition....you should start there.

Comment: I have a graphql api that writes and reads some cookies. I want to host this api in an azure function.

Comment: This looks like a complex scenario...I cannot give you a proper advice without knowing the whole picture.

Comment: I had it working with express, and now I need to have it working on the azure function. I find it weird that I can set headers, body, and status code, but not cookies in the http trigger response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) in the headers should work.

Ex:

```
var exdate = new Date(2018, 5, 1);
context.res = {
    body: "<b> this totally works</b> <i> nice</i>",
    status: 201,
    headers: {
        'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test; Expires=' + exdate.toUTCString() + ';'
    }
};
context.done();
```